# I can't drag or drop anything to layout graphical interface in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am using Eclipse. I can't Drag or Drop anything into graphical interface of my xml file.
When ever I drag anything like a button or a text view it just shows that position dotted block and just stuck at there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
     android:text="text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
     android:text="text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
     android:text="Type your secret password"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I feel like glitches happen often with XML files in Android Eclipse. My best suggestion (when there are problems with no apparent reason) would be to create a new XML file from scratch, perhaps even with a copy + paste. You only have 4 TextViews anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied and pasted your code into a `RelativeLayout` file I just made on Eclipse, and it seems to be working fine. Have you tried maybe playing around with the height and width of the `TextViews` or adding background images to the buttons to try and locate them easier? It is possible the `wrap_content` may be making it too small. And if this is your first time using Android layouts, I would recommend using `LinearLayout` instead. `RelativeLayout` can be tough and hard to work with, even for more experienced programmers.